# CSS overflow not working with flex-grow or width/height in per cent

Tags: django, flexbox, height, width, overflow

I am facing a problem that I don't really understand with the overflow of CSS.

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

.simulations {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.waiting-list {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.waiting-list h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.waiting-list .list {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.waiting-list .list .element {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button img {
    margin: auto;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML (I am using Django):

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/test.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="simulations">
            <div class="waiting-list">
                <h3>Waiting list</h3>
                <div class="list">
                    {% for i in "x"|rjust:"10" %}
                        <div>
                            <div class="element">
                                <h4>Title</h4>
                                <p>size</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-prettycons-lineal-prettycons/49/000000/external-enter-essentials-prettycons-lineal-prettycons.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[Visual of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9hwo.png)

As you can see on the picture, the waiting list class is going over the button instead of overflowing on x axis and keeping the right button at the plae that it should be. When I apply a width properties to the waiting-list class, it works perfectly but it's no longer responsive to the scrren size.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is all you need to show you the problem. The picture is made from this code. I simplify the problem with this code because the original one is too big.